# how clear styleclass and reload page in primefaces/jsf

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm a selectBooleanCheckbox in my form when he is selected, need him chance your styleClass but I can't do this.

I use primefaces 5.1 and jsf 2.2.

My xhtml:

```
 <h:outputLabel id="telefoneModule" styleClass="#{editPclientMB.isExtraModules('PHONE_SUPPORT')}">Telefone</h:outputLabel
```

My Bean

```
public String isExtraModules(String moduleName){
    if (this.extraModules.contains(moduleName))
        return "moduleCell";
    else
        return "ui-panelgrid-cel";
}
```

Comment: I fail to see the actual problem

Comment: I suspect the problem is related to the mentioned but not shown selectBooleanCheckbox. The problem could be a lack of an ajax update on selectBooleanCheckbox's value change.